# Maximum number of database queries per view

Tags: django, database, django-views, django-queryset, django-orm

I am currently working on a view that has multiple database queries in it (currently 10 but in the end it will be most likely 50 or more) -> My aim is to built a html page with a large table for monthly reporting purposes with all kind of data from the database (kind of a dashboard).

My question 1: Is my approach of putting 50 or more queriesin a view sensible or will it make the page loading time very slow. If it is not sensible, what is the best practice to built a view with a lot of data from various sources (Eg. build only a few large queries that somehow chain together multiple smaller queries (in order to query the database less often) and then separate and slice and dice the data from the queryset via python?

My question 2: Does it make any difference in efficiency whether I design my queries like this:

```
    data = Testdata3.objects.all()
    data1 = data.filter(key__regex=r'abc123$').order_by('date').values('date','performance')
    data2 = data.filter(key__regex=r'def456$').order_by('date').values('date','performance')
    data3 = data.filter(key__regex=r'ghi789').order_by('date').values('date','performance')
```

or like this:

```
    data1 = Testdata3.objects.filter(key__regex=r'abc123$').order_by('date').values('date','performance')
    data2 = Testdata3.objects.filter(key__regex=r'def456$').order_by('date').values('date','performance')
    data3 = Testdata3.objects.filter(key__regex=r'ghi789').order_by('date').values('date','performance')
```

My assumption would be that the first way is more efficient since I hit the database only once and then filter down from my data object instead of from the database.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. Both pieces of code hit the database three times.

Comment: Thanks! So do you know of any best practice for designing a view with so many queries or is this just the way to go?

Comment: Well 50 queries doesn't sound outrageous. But if you're really concerned you could combine these three into a single query with a Q or even a single regex with `|`, then include the key in the results and filter/sort them by the key in Python.